# c# associative array with dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, associative-array

I want to build an Dictonary like this :

```
Dictionary<String, ArrayList> myDic = new Dictionary<String, ArrayList>();
```

in the end i want a structure like :

```
["blabla"] => array(1,2,3)
["foo"] => array(1,4,6,8) 
.......
```

to build this i run in a loop and in every loop build some strings ,

**first question  :**

how to check every time if this string exists
in the dictionary , if its not exists open a new entry in dictionary with one element in the array list, if exists only add another element to the array list

**and another question**:

how can i sort this dictionary according to number of elements in the array list(In descending order) like :

```
["foo"] => array(1,4,6,2,8)     
["bar"] => array(4,6,2,8) 
["bla"] => array(1,2,3)
["blo"] => array(1,2)    
    .......
```

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ArrayList` you should use an array or `List<T>`. Assuming you have a `Dictionary<string, int>` called source this should work:

```
var items = source
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .Select(grp => new { Key = grp.Key, Items = grp.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray() })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Items.Length);
```

To explain, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` so can be considered a sequence of key-value pairs. Group by groups the pairs by key and then `Select` creates a sequence of an anonymous type which contains the key and associated values in a Key and Items property respectively. This sequence is then ordered by the number of items in the `Items` array of each object.

If you want to order them by the length of the created array, you can't use a dictionary since they are not ordered.

Comment: i newbie in c# if you can explain more

Comment: If you have a variable called `source` that's a list/array/enumerable of integers, this code will give you back what you asked for: a list, in descending order by length, of groups, where each group has a key ("foo", "bar", "bla", "blo", etc.) and the list of matching items.

Answer (score 5):

Use the right tool for the job. The data structure you want is called a "multi-dictionary" - that is a dictionary that maps from a key to a sequence of values, rather than from a key to a unique value.

The [PowerCollections codebase](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) contains an implementation of MultiDictionary that *probably* does what you want. I would use it rather than writing your own.

To sort the dictionary into a sequence of key/sequence pairs ordered by the length of the sequence, I would use a LINQ query with an "order by" clause. That seems like the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a key exists in a dictionary and use the value if it does, you can use `TryGetValue`:

```
ArrayList array;
if(!myDic.TryGetValue("blabla", out array))
{
    array = new ArrayList();
    myDic["blabla"] = array;
}
array.Add(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
        if (myDic.ContainsKey(myString))
            myDic[myString].Add(myNumber);
        else
            myDic.Add(myString, new ArrayList(new int[] {myNumber}));
```